# Promise all resolvation

Tags: javascript, promise

I am playing with promises and found about `Promise.all()` if i understood correctly it resolves after all promises in arguments were resolved. I tried little code

```
var x = ["one", "two"];
var g = 1000;

function take(element, sec) {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      res(element)
    }, sec);
  })
}

Promise.all(x.map(y => {
  take(y, g);
  g+=1000;
})).then(f => {
  alert('done : ' + f);
})
```

but it Promise.all resolved instantly , is there any bug in this little piece of code or my understanding of it is bad?

Comment: `map` needs to return the value of `take`. As it stands now, you are asking `Promise.all` to resolve a list of undefineds.

Answer (score 1):

As torazaburo has already noted the `return` statement within the `map` callback is missing. Arrow functions with block syntax require an explicit `return`. Now the following assignment `g+=1000` is ignored. It isn't good practice to rely on global state anyway. Therefore I shift the expression into the `map` callback and use an arrow without block syntax:

```
var x = ["one", "two"];

function take(element, sec) {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      res(element)
    }, sec);
  })
}

Promise.all(x.map((y, i) => take(y, 1000*(i+1)))).then(f => alert('done : ' + f));
```

Comment: *"In contrast to normal arrows fat arrow functions require an explicit `return`"* - huh? There's no such thing as "normal" or "fat" arrow functions.

Comment: @naomik OK, edited it. I still think that my term is somehow fitting. An arrow with block syntax is so fat, because he's swallowed so many statements :D

Comment: I believe the term "fat arrow function" came from coffeescript where there are both "skinny arrow functions" `->` and their "fat" counterparts `=>`. The difference is `->` does not have lexical `this` whereas `=>` does.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said multiple places, you need to return the promise from your `.map()` callback in order for `Promise.all()` to work.  Here's one simple way to do that:

```
Promise.all(x.map(y => {
  var p = take(y, g);
  g+=1000;
  return p;
})).then(f => {
  alert('done : ' + f);
});
```

In this code `f` is an array of results, so it's not clear what you're trying to do in the `alert()`.